# What does this 'ls' command do?

Tags: unix, ls

From the /etc directory I run: ls -l [clst][io]?t*   and I get an output, but for the life of me I can't understand what it is doing.  Can someone help me understand and break this down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will match any file/directory having the following rules:

```
ls -l [clst][io]?t*
```

1. starts with any one of the letter `[clst]`
2. followed by any one of `i` or `o`.
3. then any one letter `?`
4. should have `t` at 4th position.
5. then have any lengths after above pattern.

Ex: `ciat.txt`